# Regexp non alphanumerical but not German characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to remove all non alpha numerical characters from a string. Except space, - and some German characters.

Example

```
regexp = "mönchengladbach."
regexp.gsub(/[^0-9a-z \-]/i, '')
=> mnchengladbach
```

I need this:

```
=> mönchengladbach
```

It should also not replace other German characters such as:

```
ä ö ü ß
```

Thanks!

Edit:

It was just me not testing properly. The IRB did not accept special characters. This works for me:

```
regexp.gsub(/[^0-9a-z \-äüöß]/i, '')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all that is not a letter or a space you can use this:

```
str.gsub(/[^\p{L}\s]+/, '')
```

I use here a negated character class, `[^\p{L}\s]` means *all that is not a letter* (in all language you want) *or a white charater* (space, tab, newlines)

`\p{L}` is an unicode character class for Letters.

You can easily add other characters you want to preserve like `-`:

```
str.gsub(/[^\p{L}\s-]+/, '')
```

example script:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

str = "mönchengladbach."

str = str.gsub(/[^\p{L}\s]+/, '#')

puts str
```

Comment: it seems {L} does not exist in ruby?

Comment: @Hendrik: it is supported on ruby 1.9 but not in older versions.

Comment: @Hendrik: you must add the encoding at the begining of the script, see my example.

Comment: @Lindrian: Yes, but since regex101.com use the php implementation of regexes, you must add the \u option to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
/[^[:alnum:] -]/
```

Note the `//i` is not necessary and no need to escape `-` when it's at the end of a `[]`